# Issue with google calendar push notification

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I tried implementing the google calendar push notification in my server.
Using the outhplayground, i was able to successfully subscribe to the service.
I am getting notifications to my registered url when a change takes place in the calendar.
The only issue is that the response that i receive doesnt have data. Its an empty response.

Could anyone tell me what the issue would be. I am using PHP code in the backend to access the request hitting my url.

authplayground code:

```
POST /calendar/v3/calendars/calendarname@gmail.com/events/watch HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 161
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer access_token
 {
  "id": "01234267-89a6-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://example.com/response" // Your receiving URL.
 }
```

Code to accept request:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($json, true);
$post_request = $_POST;
$get_request = $_REQUEST;
```

As I  was getting an empty response, i tried writing the code to accept any possible way.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: POST /calendar/v3/calendars/calendarname@gmail.com/events/watch HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 161
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer access_token
{
  "id": "01234267-89a6-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://example.com/response" // Your receiving URL.
  }

Comment: please re post your code in your question.

Comment: Please post your php code you are using for your response url page.

Comment: What php code are you using for your response url page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google sends the response in the headers as an array.

Try this:

```
$response = apache_request_headers();

if($response) {

 print_r($response);

}else {

  echo 'The apache_request_headers() did not find any headers.'; //Or google is not sending any.   

}
```

You may also try:

```
getallheaders()
```

if the apache_request_headers did not work.

Testing this can be difficult.  You may want to set up a log that sends any data your page gets to a table on your database so that you can go back and inspect to see what type of progress you are making.

Comment: the first code worked fine and i am able to get the response now. I forwarded the response to my mail to check the params and to know the details. Thanks @Joseph_J

Comment: @Vivek Cu Cool, glad you got it working.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values like this:

```
$channelId = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_ID'];
$resourceId = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_ID'];

if($channelId) {
    file_put_contents('webhook.txt', $channelId.' ||| '.$resourceId);
}
```

You can get the different `headers` here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#understanding-the-notification-message-format